# What's the cooldown on healing potions?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've noticed that, differently from Diablo II, on Diablo III there's a cooldown on Healing Potions, probably because of Healing Globes. How long is this cooldown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cooldown lasts 30 seconds. It is displayed in the item tooltip.

Comment: Do you have any source? Or is it on the tooltip on the potion?

Comment: Various websites. And it can be easily checked by looking at your watch - I did not do that though ;)